# Why don't I get output from Debug.log in an infinite loop in the Elm REPL?

Tags: elm

I'm debugging some code with an infinite loop, but it's difficult, because I can't get any log messages out. Here's a simplified case:

```
import Debug exposing (log)

f x =
    let _ = log "Hello, world!" ()
    in f x
```

If I run this at my Elm REPL like `f ()`, it infinitely loops and never prints out `"Hello, world!"` as I expect it to.

I looked at the implementation of `Debug.log` (following it to `Native.Debug.log`), but it just seems to be calling `process.stdout.write` or `console.log` synchronously, so I'm surprised that I'm not seeing any output.

Comment: I have no idea if Elm does an optimization pass, but if it were to, assigning a value to an ignored binding would likely be optimized away. Have you tried this without assigning the log value to `_`?

Comment: Well, it doesn't optimize it out in a non-infinite-recursive case: `f x = let _ = log "Hello, world!" () in 5` and then calling `f ()` does print `Hello, world!`

Comment: @w.brian A correct compiler will only ever optimize away an unused expression if it can prove that it has no side-effects. Optimizing `let _ = side_effecting_expression in foo` to `foo` would be a very incorrect optimization. PS: `let _ = ...` does not actually introduce a binding.

Comment: @sepp2k As far as the compiler is aware, log is a pure function and would be correct to optimize it away. The fact that it is impure is hidden from the compiler, and the docs state quite clearly that it should not be used in production for that very reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a bug in the Elm REPL.

## The Problem

I dove into the implementation of the Elm REPL. The relevant function is here: [Eval.Code.run](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl/blob/7f536dae34211ab27f1699f340751166c2d1ed40/src/Eval/Code.hs#L113-L124)

This `run` function seems to be the function that executes a piece of code. It looks like each line of code is executed in a subprocess, via Elm.Utils. unwrappedRun. There are two problems with the way it runs it:

- The stdout of the subprocess is not streamed; it's only returned once the whole subprocess is done. So as long as you're waiting for your code to finish evaluation, you won't see anything.
- If you hit ctrl-c to end evaluation prematurely (which works fine, and returns you back to the Elm prompt), the Elm Repl ignores the stdout that is returned to it. Notice the [pattern match for CommandFailed](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl/blob/7f536dae34211ab27f1699f340751166c2d1ed40/src/Eval/Code.hs#L123-L124):

`Left (Utils.CommandFailed _out err) ->
    throwError err`

The `Utils.CommandFailed` result helpfully includes the stdout (which is being bound to `_out`), but this code ignores it and just throws the error.

So basically this isn't anything that weird going on with the Elm compiler or runtime, just that the REPL isn't as good as it could be with respect to logged results.

## The Workaround

As a workaround, in order to debug things like infinite loops, you can

1. put some test code in a new file, `Scratch.elm`, like `x = f ()`
2. compile the code with `elm-make Scratch.elm --output scratch.js`
3. run the code with `node scratch.js`

Then output will be streamed to your terminal.

Comment: That's a pretty clever workaround; since node.js is based on v8 which is what executes javascript in the chrome web browser. It's possible to fake some of the browser stuff with [node-jsdom](https://github.com/darrylwest/node-jsdom)

Comment: Elm-REPL also uses node.js for evaluation, so it's identical to the way Elm REPL would run your code anyway.